# JFreeChart BarRenderer shows only first color of GradientPaint

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to use `GradientPaint` for my stacked bar chart to highlight the selected series, but only the first `Color` of the `GradientPaint` is shown.

```
GroupedStackedBarRenderer barRenderer = new GroupedStackedBarRenderer();
...
GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(
                        5, 5, Color.blue,
                        10, 5, Color.black,
                        true
                    );
barRenderer.setSeriesPaint(types.indexOf(t), gp1);
```

Am I missing something, or is it not working for JFreeChart?

Comment: Works for me; for specific guidance, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)that exhibits the result you expect and result you see.

Answer (score 2):

In your call to `setSeriesPaint()`, be sure to specify the same `Paint` for *each* desired key in your `KeyToGroupMap`. In a variation of [`StackedBarChartDemo4`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) illustrated below, the same variation of your `Paint` is applied to every fourth key, marked "US" in the legend.

```
Paint p1 = new GradientPaint(
    0, 0, Color.blue,
    0, 0, Color.black,
    true
);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, p1);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(4, p1);
renderer.setSeriesPaint(8, p1);
```

[image]